# jquery dialog in header file not working

Tags: jquery

I'm facing an issue with Jquery dialog box. My intention is to display a warning message to notify the user, when the user made some changes in the HTML form and tries to leave the page by clicking any of the hyperlinks. But the jquery dialog box is not appearing when I change the form values and click any of the hyperlinks in the page.

Things to note:

This code is in a master ftl file and all my other ftl files will be injected to this file.
I have the same code in another page and when the user clicks cancel button in the page after made some changes to form fields, the dialog box is displayed.
The normal java script alert inside my if condition (please refer the code below) is displaying, but the jquery dialog box is not appearing.

Appreciate your help and Thanks in advance.

## CSS Includes

```
<title><@tiles.getAsString name="title" ignore=true /></title>
        <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"></meta>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
        <@tiles.insertAttribute name='metas' ignore=true/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <link href="/styles/<@tiles.getAsString name='cssFilename' ignore=true/>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/styles/<@tiles.getAsString name='cssErrorFilename' ignore=true/>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/styles/login-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/styles/jtable-green.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/css/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

## Script lib Includes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jtable.js" ></script>
```

## HTML Div Part

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="diaBack" class="dialog" title="Are You Sure!">
        <p>
            Are you sure you want to cancel the changes.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Jquery Script part

```
 $("a").click(function(e)
     {

            if ($("#UnsavedChanges").val() == "1") 
            {
                alert("You have done some changes");
                $("#diaBack").dialog({
                            modal: true, 
                            show: "slide",
                            dialogClass: "myTitleClass", 
                            width: defaultDialogWidth, 
                            buttons: {
                                "OK": function() { document.location =  "/tickerdefinitions"; },
                            }
                        });; 
            }
      });
```

Comment: did you include the css files also?

Comment: What is the z-index of the dialog?

Comment: Please provide us jsfiddle demo to save our(your too) time!

Comment: I smell here asp.NET although Tag is not added

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `window.onbeforeunload = function(){ confirm("Are you sure you want to leave?") }`

Comment: @JeremyThille , Hi , default alert is NOT appealing to user  , bootstrap , jquery alert popup is amazing as UI design !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses. Did a couple of things and its worked.

I was getting the script error saying "defaultDialogWidth is undefined". Not sure why. So changed that to 350. Also replaced the alert line with e.preventDefault();.